# IdentityServer4 Client Secret Max Length Default Client_Invalid Error Message

Tags: c#, identityserver4, .net-5

The client Secret default value seems to be 101 characters. How to send client_secret with varying length > 101 ?

Answer (score 2):

While adding IdentityServer at the startup.cs file, there is an options to change default values of client secret and other parameters. Default value is 101 character limit

```
 var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(
options=> options.InputLengthRestrictions.ClientSecret=750)
```